NuxtJS - Vuefire Firebase error auth/invalid-api-key when deploying with Docker
I have an app that uses Nuxt (SSR) + Vuefire for auth that I am trying to deploy to Cloud Run.
When running my local dev server or building and previewing the app with npx nuxi build + npx nuxi preview, everything works fine.
However, when running my Docker image, I am getting a (auth/invalid-api-key) error.
All my environment variables are properly defined in my nuxt.config.ts file, in my Dockerfile and in my .env file and I made sure to stick to the convention that dictates that env variables names should reflect the nesting structure of the defineNuxtConfig object.
When running the container in interactive mode and using printenv, I can see that all the variables are there, and assigned the correct values.
If I hardcode the api key in the Dockerfile, the error goes away.
I have therefore tried assigning default values dummy values to my variables like so:

apiKey: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY || "mock_key"

as per this post, but still no luck.
Any other leads I could follow to understand where is the problem coming from?

After spending a long time finding similar issues and understanding how they had been resolved, I tried to apply default assignments to the vuefire object itself like so:
  vuefire: {
    config: {
      apiKey: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY || "mock_key",
      authDomain: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN || "mock_key",
      projectId: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID || "mock_key",
      storageBucket:
        process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET || "mock_key",
      appId: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID || "mock_key",
    },
    auth: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  }


And this was enough to get me sorted.
Other people resorted to coercing the env variable like so:

apiKey: String(process.env.NEXT_PRIVATE_APIKEY)

Or:

apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PRIVATE_APIKEY + ""

I am still really why this happens but this is how it can be resolved.
